# Lead calcuation for spiral bevel gear

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, machining

I want to machine a spiral bevel gear on a manual universal milling machine using a involuter  gear cutter. I also have a differential indexing setup for this job. But the difficulty I am facing is that how to calculate lead for this gear so that I can link up indexing head with feed . All I could find online with some research was that mean bevel angle is 35~40 degree. I would appreciate some links to reliable sources for more research

Comment: Welcome to Engineering SE! Resource-finding questions aren't [on-topic](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here but it seems like you could get a solid answer to your question otherwise. Could you provide a link to the information you've already found? Also a diagram could help clarify exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Possibly Ivan Law : Gears and Gear Cutting?